# A Cryptic Book Cliche

Tags: cipher

There is a strange bookcase at the end of a chapel's corridor that is pitch black, save for a few lanterns lighting the way. As you approach the bookcase, you notice six conspicuous books with unique colors. These unique colors being: red, purple, white, gold, blue, and green. A note is laying in front of the books, telling you of a secret passage that activates when you pull one of the books. The note also reads "The location is in the titles". The six books have the following titles.

- The Church's Hidden Archives
- Purifying in The Tub
- Bat out of Hell
- Vowels with Noah: AEIOU
- God's Word is True
- The Devil's Tempting Lies

Which book do you pull to find the passage and why?

Hint 1

> Upon closer inspection, the note seems to emphasize that the middle four titles are more important

Comment: You do not need any background knowledge to solve this.

Comment: FWIW I thought the title, backstory, and book names were really interesting and drew me in. Would have been nice to go a notch or two more difficult and incorporate all six books into a solution. But good start!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the book to pull to find the passage is:

> *God's Word is True* - the **blue** book.

Because 'The location is in the titles' and:

> the last letters of the four central books spell **b-l-u-e**. (Tu**b**-Hel**l**-AEIO**U**-Tru**e**)